# how to setting error page for IntegrityException in yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

How i can show custom Error Page instead of Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException Error in Yii 2

How i can catch and throw exception for this in Yii 2.0

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html

Comment: it's not my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following approach. Add custom callback function on event `\yii\web\Response::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND` where you can check current exception and then redefine response content or redirect user wherever you want.

For example You can add into your config something like this:

```
'response' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
    'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
        $exception = \Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;
        /* @var \yii\web\Response $response */
        $response = $event->sender;

        if ($response->isServerError && is_a($exception, \yii\db\IntegrityException::class)) {
            // here you can define custom message to show
            $response->data = 'Integrity exception: ' . $exception->getMessage();

            // or render custom view
            //$response->data = \Yii::$app->getView()->render('@app/views/site/error.php', ['exception' => $exception]);

            // or redirect...
            //$response->redirect('https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=Integrity+exception+Yii2');
        }
    },
],
```

Comment: my question is , how can i do it with try & catch statement ?

Comment: @NarimanDelavary so what's the problem exactly? As for me - it's quite simple, but actual implementation (where you should put your try-catch block) will depends on your needs. You even have a link to the manual in comments to your question. Have you tried to do it yourself?

Comment: Thanks Maxim.My Problem Is Solved